# Docker Mac M1 issue No matching for manifest

Tags: docker, macos, apple-m1

```
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine
   2 |     VOLUME /tmp
   3 |     COPY build/libs/*.jar myapp.jar
--------------------
```

> ERROR: failed to solve: adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine:
> no match for platform in manifest
> sha256:ed7ea16ca04b09cb381a094dff07c5d5ce5f0ead97540fcfc4b67c054e25e217:
> not found

Any help on this issue.I am using Mac M1 and docker getting this error while executing docker file.

I am getting this error while executing a script file which is calling the docker file.

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY build/libs/*.jar myapp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xmx800m", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=cloud", "/myApp.jar"]
```

The same script  is executing well in windows system

Comment: Try https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5975#issuecomment-942403670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The architecture for the **M1 Mac** and **Windows** is diff that's the reason behind the error.

> adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine: no match for platform in
> manifest

Above error mean the image that you are trying is not available for playgform **Macbook**. i guess it is **OS/ARCH : linuxamd64**

Check for the **OS/ARCH** : **ARM** and it will work.

Check here all available ARM options : https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11/tags?page=1&name=jre-11

Which is suitable for you **Slim, nightly** release as per need.

**Update** :

As Rick mentioned you can use the `--platform` and cross-run it, but there could be chances of **Compatibility, Performance**.

Recommended is to use **native images** whenever possible for **performance** and **compatibility**.

you can build your docker image with **buildx** if building on Mac creates Multi-platform images.

Comment: keep in mind that you can cross run if you're explicit about it like `$ docker run --platform=linux/amd64 -ti --rm adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine`

Comment: Yes no doubt about that you are right, AMD images on ARM may not always work seamlessly and lead to further errors. Native images generally perform better. i faced an issue while running TensorFlow AMD on ARM and wasted days solving one-by-one errors.